# Getting error while executing Android studio app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to android app
I installed android studio and trying to execute sample my application, while opening emulator getting below error.

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Hax is enabled
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools` -> `Android` -> `AVD Manager` -> click `Edit` and uncheck the `Enable Device Frame` checkbox.

Comment: Getting same error with 
C:\......AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!